# How to Handle (Ghost) Duplicate Files and Use Drag Move in Intellij Language Resource Bundle?

Tags: java, resources, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

Created Strange Files: Language Bundles
[image]

It's Causing Problems: Renaming Issues, Drag and Drop Not Working, Files Staying in the Same Directory in Finder

[image]

In IntelliJ, I See It Twice as Shown in the Screenshot. I've Already Tried Deleting, Re-adding, and Renaming Without Success.